# Why it returns 302 and no error message returns with `If` in `Menu`?

Tags: scala, lift

Lift code in `Boot.scala`:

```
Menu.i("Topic") / "topic" >> If(() => false, "myerror")
```

From the document of `If`:

```
/**
 * If the test returns True, the page can be accessed, otherwise,
 * the result of FailMsg will be sent as a response to the browser.
 * If the Loc cannot be accessed, it will not be displayed in menus.
 *
 * @param test -- the function that tests access to the page
 * @param failMsg -- what to return the the browser (e.g., 304, etc.) if
 * the page is accessed.
 */
case class If(test: () => Boolean, failMsg: FailMsg) extends AnyLocParam
```

It says: `otherwise, the result of FailMsg will be sent as a response to the browser`. So I expect it returns a http code of 5xx with error message `myerror`, but it not, it redirects to the index page `/` instead.

And with curl:

```
➜  ~  curl http://localhost:8080/topic -I
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5gqkx8azu8gh1u3avyjds3wl;Path=/
Location: /
Expires: Tue, 16 Jul 2013 05:18:02 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, private, no-store
Content-Type: text/plain
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Tue, 16 Jul 2013 05:18:02 GMT
X-Lift-Version: 2.5
Server: Jetty(8.1.7.v20120910)
```

Why it returns 302? And where is my error message `myerror`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing a redirect is that there's an implicit conversion from a `String` to a redirect to / (by default) with a Lift error notice set.

The string is used as the value of the error notice, which you can see displayed if you have Lift notices included on the page. It looks like the implicit is called `strToFailMsg`.

The recipe *Access Restriction by HTTP Header* in the [Lift Cookbook](http://cookbook.liftweb.net) touches on this briefly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Menu.i("Topic") / "topic" >> If(() => false, RedirectResponse("/"))
```

Comment: I don't want it to direct to `/`(and it does now), I want it to show the error

Comment: In console ? Its webapp, You can redirect to some 404 page which will show You an error :) You can always put there function which will log in console but then redirect.

Comment: Sorry, not in console. You can see the document in my question: `otherwise, the result of FailMsg will be sent as a response to the browser`. It behaviors different from the document.

Comment: But heh, You mean alert ? or display it to page.

Comment: If alert use lift js functions. Or some lifts responses : http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-9.html

Answer (score 0):

What Lift version are you using?

In both Lift 2.4 and Lift 2.5, FailMsg is a alias of `() ⇒ LiftResponse`, so just simply provide it with `NotFoundResponse("myerror")` should work.

```
Menu.i("Topic") / "topic" >> If(() => false, () => net.liftweb.http.NotFoundResponse("myerror"))
```